# meteor build app can't install on android phone

Tags: android, meteor, hybrid-mobile-app

I generated a apk file by running

```
meteor build ~/output-dir --server=myapp.meteor.com
```

,
then got **`release-unsigned.apk`** in the folder **`output-dir`**, it looks good.

I copy this apk file to my Android phone and tried to install it, after install guide, it shows message **`App not installed`**.

I have installed some apk files built by java on my phone before, it works, so is there something I need handle when I install apk file built by meteor?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As the [documentation](http://developer.android.com/tools/publishing/app-signing.html) states, you can't install unsigned applications on your Android phone:

> Android requires that all apps be digitally signed with a certificate
>   before they can be installed.

As far as I can tell, you have the following two options to run your app:

- Use an emulator to run your unsigned app or
- sign your app.

To sign your app, you can use the steps, described in the [Meteor guide for submitting Android apps to the Play Store](https://github.com/meteor/meteor/wiki/How-to-submit-your-Android-app-to-Play-Store):

1. Generate a private key using the [**`keytool`**](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/technotes/tools/windows/keytool.html) (skip this step, in case you already have a private key generated):

---

```
keytool -genkey -alias your-app-name -keyalg RSA -keysize 2048 -validity 10000
```

2. Sign your app using the [**`jarsigner`**](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/technotes/tools/windows/jarsigner.html) tool:

---

```
jarsigner -verbose -sigalg SHA1withRSA -digestalg SHA1 unaligned.apk your-app-name
```

---

After that, you should be able to install and run your application on your Android phone.